# DBRef resolution is not supported

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, dbref

I can't find what I'm doing wrong. What I want is to make a reference from the account class to the vehicles

```
@Document(collection = "cuentas")
public class CuentaDTO {
    @Id
    @NonNull
    private String cuentaId = UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0,3);
    private String nombre;
    private String telefono;
    private String cedula;
    private Integer edad;
    //@Field("placa")
    @DBRef()
    private VehiculoDTO vehiculoDTO;

    public CuentaDTO(@NonNull String cuentaId, String nombre, String telefono, String 
     cedula, Integer edad, VehiculoDTO vehiculoDTO) {
        this.cuentaId = cuentaId;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.telefono = telefono;
        this.cedula = cedula;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.vehiculoDTO = vehiculoDTO;
    }

    public String getCuentaId() {
        return cuentaId;
    }

    public void setCuentaId(String cuentaId) {
        this.cuentaId = cuentaId;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }

    public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    public String getCedula() {
        return cedula;
    }

    public void setCedula(String cedula) {
        this.cedula = cedula;
    }

    public Integer getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    public void setEdad(Integer edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public VehiculoDTO getVehiculo() {
        return vehiculoDTO;
    }

    public void setVehiculo(VehiculoDTO vehiculoDTO) {
        this.vehiculoDTO = vehiculoDTO;
    }
}
```

Second entity

```
@Document(collection = "vehiculos")
public class VehiculoDTO {

    @Id
    private String placa;
    private String marca;
    private Integer modelo;
    private Integer capacidad;
    private String tipo;

    public VehiculoDTO(String placa, String marca, Integer modelo, Integer capacidad, 
    String tipo) {
        this.placa = placa;
        this.marca = marca;
        this.modelo = modelo;
        this.capacidad = capacidad;
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public String getPlaca() {
        return placa;
    }

    public void setPlaca(String placa) {
        this.placa = placa;
    }

    public String getMarca() {
        return marca;
    }

    public void setMarca(String marca) {
        this.marca = marca;
    }

    public Integer getModelo() {
        return modelo;
    }

    public void setModelo(Integer modelo) {
        this.modelo = modelo;
    }

    public Integer getCapacidad() {
        return capacidad;
    }

    public void setCapacidad(Integer capacidad) {
        this.capacidad = capacidad;
    }

    public String getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(String tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }
}
```

This is the error I get
This application has no configured error view, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

```
Mon Apr 25 21:30:37 COT 2022
[c7e63705-15] There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
DBRef resolution is not supported!
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: DBRef resolution is not supported!
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.NoOpDbRefResolver.handle(NoOpDbRefResolver.java:71)
    Suppressed: The stacktrace has been enhanced by Reactor, refer to additional information below: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Handler com.sofka.app.transportecargaback.Cuenta.controller.CuentaController#findALl() [DispatcherHandler]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ springfox.boot.starter.autoconfigure.SwaggerUiWebFluxConfiguration$CustomWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/cuenta" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.NoOpDbRefResolver.handle(NoOpDbRefResolver.java:71)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.NoOpDbRefResolver.fetch(NoOpDbRefResolver.java:58)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readRef(MappingMongoConverter.java:1630)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.bulkReadAndConvertDBRefs(MappingMongoConverter.java:1576)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readDBRef(MappingMongoConverter.java:1549)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$ConversionContext.convert(MappingMongoConverter.java:2068)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1779)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$AssociationAwareMongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1833)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$AssociationAwareMongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1791)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.java:74)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.java:53)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.extractInvocationArguments(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:276)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator$EntityInstantiatorAdapter.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:248)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:89)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:390)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readDocument(MappingMongoConverter.java:356)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:292)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:288)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ReactiveMongoTemplate$ReadDocumentCallback.doWith(ReactiveMongoTemplate.java:3247)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:376)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:251)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink.drain(FluxCreate.java:793)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink.next(FluxCreate.java:718)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$SerializedFluxSink.next(FluxCreate.java:154)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
        at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.BatchCursorFlux.lambda$recurseCursor$4(BatchCursorFlux.java:94)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:171)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:854)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.success(MonoCreate.java:165)
        at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.MongoOperationPublisher.lambda$sinkToCallback$30(MongoOperationPublisher.java:549)
        at com.mongodb.internal.operation.AsyncQueryBatchCursor.next(AsyncQueryBatchCursor.java:167)
        at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.BatchCursor.lambda$next$0(BatchCursor.java:35)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate.subscribe(MonoCreate.java:57)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribeWith(Mono.java:4515)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4232)
        at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.BatchCursorFlux.recurseCursor(BatchCursorFlux.java:104)
        at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.BatchCursorFlux.lambda$subscribe$0(BatchCursorFlux.java:56)
        at reactor.core.publisher.LambdaMonoSubscriber.onNext(LambdaMonoSubscriber.java:171)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:249)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.success(MonoCreate.java:165)
        at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.MongoOperationPublisher.lambda$sinkToCallback$30(MongoOperationPublisher.java:549)
        at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.OperationExecutorImpl.lambda$execute$2(OperationExecutorImpl.java:92)
        at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:48)
        at com.mongodb.internal.async.function.AsyncCallbackSupplier.lambda$whenComplete$1(AsyncCallbackSupplier.java:95)
        at com.mongodb.internal.async.function.RetryingAsyncCallbackSupplier$RetryingCallback.onResult(RetryingAsyncCallbackSupplier.java:114)
        at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:48)
        at com.mongodb.internal.async.function.AsyncCallbackSupplier.lambda$whenComplete$1(AsyncCallbackSupplier.java:95)
        at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:48)
        at com.mongodb.internal.async.function.AsyncCallbackSupplier.lambda$whenComplete$1(AsyncCallbackSupplier.java:95)
        at com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation$2.onResult(FindOperation.java:762)
        at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandOperationHelper.lambda$transformingReadCallback$10(CommandOperationHelper.java:329)
        at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:48)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor$2.onResult(DefaultServer.java:280)
        at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:48)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandProtocolImpl$1.onResult(CommandProtocolImpl.java:84)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection$1.onResult(DefaultConnectionPool.java:687)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection$2.onResult(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:159)
        at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:48)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$2$1.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:526)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$2$1.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:503)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback$MessageCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:815)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback$MessageCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:782)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:650)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:647)
        at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream.readAsync(NettyStream.java:319)
        at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream.readAsync(NettyStream.java:266)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.readAsync(InternalStreamConnection.java:647)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.access$600(InternalStreamConnection.java:86)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:772)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:757)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:650)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:647)
        at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream.readAsync(NettyStream.java:319)
        at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream.handleReadResponse(NettyStream.java:347)
        at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream.access$1100(NettyStream.java:105)
        at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream$InboundBufferHandler.channelRead0(NettyStream.java:421)
        at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream$InboundBufferHandler.channelRead0(NettyStream.java:418)
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1372)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1235)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1284)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:510)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:449)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:279)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

I thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You missed mapping in VehiculoDTO. When you do reference you need to set it on both sides. Of course, you need to handle the assignment for it.

```java
@Document(collection = "vehiculos")
public class VehiculoDTO {

    @Id
    private String placa;
    private String marca;
    private Integer modelo;
    private Integer capacidad;
    private String tipo;
    @DBRef
    private CuentaDTO cuentaDTO;

    public VehiculoDTO(String placa, String marca, Integer modelo, Integer capacidad, 
    String tipo) {
        this.placa = placa;
        this.marca = marca;
        this.modelo = modelo;
        this.capacidad = capacidad;
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public String getPlaca() {
        return placa;
    }

    public void setPlaca(String placa) {
        this.placa = placa;
    }

    public String getMarca() {
        return marca;
    }

    public void setMarca(String marca) {
        this.marca = marca;
    }

    public Integer getModelo() {
        return modelo;
    }

    public void setModelo(Integer modelo) {
        this.modelo = modelo;
    }

    public Integer getCapacidad() {
        return capacidad;
    }

    public void setCapacidad(Integer capacidad) {
        this.capacidad = capacidad;
    }

    public String getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(String tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }
    
    public String getCuentaDTO() {
        return cuentaDTO;
    }

    public void setCuentaDTO(String cuentaDTO) {
        this.cuentaDTO = cuentaDTO;
    }
```

**Second possible reason:**

I found similar issue on GitHub questions for [spring-data-mongo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues/3015)

The problem may occur if you use in Maven or Gradle `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive` which not support @DBref mapping.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Try to use instead:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta per no me funciono, muchas gracias!

Comment: @MarianaLopez, You missed mapping in VehiculoDTO. When you do reference you need to set it on both sides. Add to `VehiculoDTO`  field `@DBRef private CuentaDTO cuentaDTO;`. Of course you need to handle assignment for it